# Cannot connect() twice to the same server in one client

Tags: c, networking, tcp, network-programming, client-server

I have a server and 2 clients (clients are the same application) and it is a log in / send information about users system.

I can connect and log in with both clients (one at a time) but when I try and do more with the client after logging in, the server does not receive any information the 2nd time.

Server:

```
int main () {

//Create users
Users client[2];

client[0].PortNumber = 20000;
client[0].online = false;
sprintf(&client[0].userName[0], "Albert");
sprintf(&client[0].ipAddress[0], "127.0.0.1");

client[1].PortNumber = 20000;
client[1].online = false;
sprintf(&client[1].userName[0], "Monique");
sprintf(&client[1].ipAddress[0], "127.0.0.1");


//Set up all the connection stuff
struct sockaddr_in SvrAddr;
SOCKET WelcomeSocket, ConnectionSocket;
int PortNumber = 20000;
int result;
char IPAddress[] = "127.0.0.1";
char RxBuffer[512];
char TxBuffer[128];


WORD wVersionRequested; 
WSADATA wsaData; 

wVersionRequested = MAKEWORD(2,2); //For Server 


if(WSAStartup(wVersionRequested, &wsaData) != 0) 
    return -1;


//Setting up the welcome socket
WelcomeSocket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);

//Setting up the sockaddr svraddr structure
SvrAddr.sin_family = AF_INET;
SvrAddr.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr(IPAddress);
SvrAddr.sin_port = htons(PortNumber);


//Bind
bind(WelcomeSocket, (sockaddr*)&SvrAddr, sizeof(SvrAddr));

//listening
listen(WelcomeSocket, 5);

//temp users

Login temp;//, temp2;
RequestInfo temp2;

int decide = 0;

while (1) {
//Beginning to start first client connection
ConnectionSocket = accept(WelcomeSocket, NULL, NULL);


//try and do a top down sequence, accept, recv, process, close for one packet
//then repeat for 2nd packet
//
int n = 0;

    n = recv(ConnectionSocket, RxBuffer, sizeof(RxBuffer), 0);

    //see what the size of the received thing is and base memcpy based on the size
    //if (n == sizeof(struct Login)) {

        memcpy(&temp, RxBuffer, sizeof(struct Login));
        decide = temp.message;

    //  cout << " Login struct " << endl;
    //}

    //else if (n == sizeof(struct RequestInfo)) {

    //  memcpy(&temp2, RxBuffer, sizeof(struct Login));
    //  decide = temp2.message;

        //cout << "Request struct" << endl;
    //}


    //cout << temp.message << temp.userName << endl << endl;

    //check which message type is being sent
    switch(decide) {

    //if message type 1
    case 1 :
        cout << "Case 1" << endl << endl;
        for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {

            //if receieved username matches with any username in the database
            if (strcmp(temp.userName, client[i].userName) == 0) {
                //create temporary Login object to send acknowledgement
                Login temporary;

                //assign the recieved login packet information to the matched one in database
                strcpy(temporary.userName, temp.userName);
                temporary.online = true;
                temporary.message = 2;

                //set logged in client to online
                client[i].online = true;

                cout << "Username: " << client[i].userName << endl << "Online status: " << client[i].online << endl << endl;

                //send the acknowledgement packet
                send(ConnectionSocket, (char *)&temporary, sizeof(struct Login), 0);
                closesocket(ConnectionSocket);
            }

        }
        break;

    //if message type 3
    case 3 :
        cout << "Case 3" << endl << endl;
        cout << "User being searched for: " << temp2.userName << endl << endl;
        for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {

            //if receieved username matches with any username in the database
            if (strcmp(temp.userName, client[i].userName) == 0) {
                client[i].message = 4;
                //send the acknowledgement packet
                send(ConnectionSocket, (char *)&client[i], sizeof(struct Users), 0);
                closesocket(ConnectionSocket);
            }

        }
        break;

    default :
        closesocket(ConnectionSocket);
        break;


    //}

    //closesocket(ConnectionSocket);
}

    cout << "End of while loop." << endl << endl << endl;

}

//closesocket(ConnectionSocket);
WSACleanup();
}
```

Client:

```
   int main () {

struct sockaddr_in SvrAddr;
SOCKET ClientSocket;
int PortNumber = 20000;
char IPAddress[] = "127.0.0.1";
//char message[] = "Hello this is the client.";
char RxBuffer[128];

WORD wVersionRequested; 
WSADATA wsaData; 

wVersionRequested = MAKEWORD(2,3); //For Client 

if(WSAStartup(wVersionRequested, &wsaData) != 0) 
    return -1; 


ClientSocket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);

SvrAddr.sin_family = AF_INET;
SvrAddr.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr(IPAddress);
SvrAddr.sin_port = htons(PortNumber);




//cout << "Name: ";
//cin >> login;

//Send request to login
int log;
int listenerFlag = 0;
char * name = new char[128];
char * request = new char[128];
Login client;
Login talkto;
Users userReceived;



    cout << "To login press (1) to end press (2). ";
    cin >> log;
    flushall();

    if (log == 1) {

        cout << "Username : ";
        scanf("%s", client.userName);
        cout << endl;
        flushall();

        //Set client login info
        client.message = 1;

        connect(ClientSocket, (sockaddr*)&SvrAddr, sizeof(SvrAddr));

        //Send login structure to server
        send(ClientSocket, (char *)&client, sizeof(struct Login), 0);

        //Recieve acknowledgement
        recv(ClientSocket, RxBuffer, sizeof(RxBuffer), 0);

        closesocket(ClientSocket);

        cout << "You have logged in." << endl << endl;

        //create temp users
        Login temp;

        memcpy(&temp, RxBuffer, sizeof(struct Login));



        //If logged in and received a message of type 2 (acknowledgement)
        if (temp.message == 2) {

            cout << "Do you want to be a listener or enter user name to talk to? (1 for listener) (2 to enter user):" << endl;
            cin >> listenerFlag;

            //get client information
            if (listenerFlag == 2) {

                cout << "Username : ";
                scanf("%s", talkto.userName);
                flushall();
                talkto.message = 3;

                connect(ClientSocket, (sockaddr*)&SvrAddr, sizeof(SvrAddr));

                //Send login structure to server
                send(ClientSocket, (char *)&client, sizeof(struct Login), 0);

                //Recieve acknowledgement
                recv(ClientSocket, RxBuffer, sizeof(RxBuffer), 0);

                Users receivedPacket;

                memcpy(&receivedPacket, RxBuffer, sizeof(struct Users));

                closesocket(ClientSocket);

                cout << "User: " << receivedPacket.userName << endl << "Online status: " << receivedPacket.online << endl;


            }

            /*
            //do listening stuff
            else if (listenerFlag == 1) {

            }
        }
        */
    }

    else if (log == 2) {

        cout << "Goodbye.";
        closesocket(ClientSocket);

    }


WSACleanup();

} // end of first if 

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The server needs to handle each accepted socket in a separate thread, and those threads need to exit the reading loop when end of stream or an error is encountered on the socket.

Comment: I am not using threads, just basic connect, accept, recv, send, close with c programming

Comment: Then you can't service clients concurrently. But you need to at least pay attention to exiting the reading loop at EOS etc. You aren't doing that at the moment, so your server gets stuck servicing one client.

Comment: My server services one client at a time. So a client logs in, close connection, another client connects, logs in, close connection. But when I log in and the connection is closed, I want to reconnect to get another client's information but the server doesn't receive information the 2nd time

Comment: Alright I have fixed it. I just had to call my socket() after the first connection was closed

Answer (score 0):

I just had to re call my socket() after the first connection closed and it worked

Comment: That's not a correct explanation or answer. You only needed to close the first connection before trying to *use* the second one. When you called socket(), or indeed connect(), has nothing to do with it.